# Why does main function differ from other function from stack point of view

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, stack-trace

I'm studying to use gdb and i got little confused. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void g(char *password) {
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
if(argc > 1)
    {
        g(argv[1]);
    } 
}
```

So with the regular function (`g()` in this example) if I want to examine function arguments, that would be ebp+8`, ebp+12.. etc. But in`main`function when I'm trying to examine command line arguments (for example`argv[1]`)It appears that previous way of examining arguments doesn't work out in this case. So my questions are:

1. Is memory for argv allocated dynamically(with something like `malloc`)?
2. Why does different size of argument changes address of `argv` itself?(With "A" it was `0xbffff084` but with "A"x10 it was `0xbffff074`)
3. Why is `argv` so far from ebp?(In my case ebp appeared in `0xbfffefe8` and `argv` `0xbffff084` when I provided `"A"` as command line argument)
4. What is between command line arguments and ebp register?
5. And final question(Its not about this subject but...)
   How to view the actual content of the file? I mean when program is run before assembly starts there are some instructions that are being run. For example to check if file is compatible with your operating system and etc...
   Sorry if question sounds silly I'm new with gdb. Thank you.

Comment: The compatibility etc is done by the OS/dynamic linker, that code is not in the binary.

Comment: GCC could do many funny things with the function, depending on settings/flags etc, so it's not guaranteed the arguments will be where you expect them. If you want to make sure no prologue is generated (then they'll be at `ESP + 4, ESP + 8` etc), there's an option for it, `__declspec(naked)` in MSVC, probably something similar in GCC.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen How does the OS determine that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Nope, the memory is not dynamically allocated. In the function before `main` (`_start`), `argv` and `argc` are pushed onto the stack for usage with `main`
2. The change in address has nothing to do with the number of arguments. It could be the batting of a butterfly's wings in another process which causes this
3. This is implementation dependent. It is hard to tell. But you can run this command in GDB to see for yourself:

   ```
   disass _start
   ```
4. ^^^

Comment: So with that command I get code that is being run before main function? Is this the code that runs the first when i run program?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this clarifies. Discovered this when assembling the same code with GCC and with GAS:

```
# GCC
# Stack is:
#ESP -> ret addr
#       argc
#       argv -> argv[0] -> "program name"
#               argv[1] -> "Key"
#               argv[2] -> "Infile"
#               argv[3] -> "Outfile"

# GAS
# Stack is:
#ESP -> argc
#       argv[0] -> "program name"
#       argv[1] -> "Key"
#       argv[2] -> "Infile"
#       argv[3] -> "Outfile"
```

And I recall that the "argv-list" is built by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

The function argument is `argv`, and is a normal parameter like any other having type `char**`.  `argv[1]` is not a function argument, it is an offset and dereference of `argv`, which you will find *is* in the expected location (which is target ABI dependent).